# How to handle Dot Char in Url Mapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp

I have a spring boot project but, I have some links from past and users are linking url on their websites and I cannot request client to change their urls. I am trying to navigate jsp link to React app. I have just found a solution but I got stuck.

Here is the link example: **abc/Dashboard.jsp#/company/88**

I am **handling abc/Dashbord** but I cannot handle abc/Dasboard.jsp to navigate a jsp page.

There is my handling endpoint;

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("")
public class DashboardController {
    @GetMapping("/Dashboard")
    public String viewBooks() {
        return "view-dashboard";
    }
}

@GetMapping("/Dashboard.jsp")
public String viewBooks2() {
    return "view-dashboard";
}
```

My Jsp Page

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>e-ŞİRKET</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    const url = window.location.href.split('/')

    if(url && url.length > 0) {
        const id = url[url.length -1]
        if(id) {
            window.location.replace(window.location.origin + '?page=company&company=' + id)
        }
    }

</script>
```

It is working for abc/Dashboard#company/88 but;
how I can handle abc/Dashboard.jsp#/company/123. I am getting 404.

Comment: Have you tried `@GetMapping("/Dashboard.jsp")`?

Comment: Yes @CryptoFool

Comment: yes alone isn't really helpful, explain what's the issue with @CryptoFool's suggestion. Also, please provide any kind of exceptions/errors you encountered, _I cannot handle..._ isn't really helpful.

Comment: I am getting 404, I have just edited question with your suggestion. @Mr.Typo